# usermod -d /path user - User is currently logged in

Tags: users

good Day

I want to make a change to a user on my CENTOS server. I want to change his default directory.
When running the command:

```
usermod -d /path_to_new_dir david
```

terminal gives me the following

```
User david is currently logged in
```

I closed all ftp sessions which I was engaged into with that user, and I am logged into terminal as root.

How do I run that command and how do I log out the user? As far as I am concerned he is not logged in...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to kick the user is by doing the following:

```
# w
damaya   pts/5     23:20    1.00s  0.00s  0.00s w
```

As we can see from "w" output, user damaya is logged in on pts/5. Now type:

```
# fuser -k /dev/pts/5
```

That will kick the user off and you can now modify their account.

Comment: another options `pkill -u damaya`  use `-9` for forceful kill

Comment: ^That's the answer. Boss!

Comment: kick everyone who is logged in: fuser -k  /dev/\`w | awk '{print $2}' |grep pts\`

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this. The user was not logged in according to `w`, but a `ps aux | grep username` showed an `imap` process running as the user. The `usermod` command ran successfully after the `imap` connection was closed.

Answer (score 3):

I would first lock the user account that he will be not abble to log in after you log out him.

`passwd -l username`

This command will block user.

If he is still logged in then uou can log him out with

`skill -KILL -u username`

After that you can modify his path to home dir and unlock account with

`passwd -u username`

Comment: I didn't know skill. ps axf |grep jenkins showed nothing, but the user was supposedly still logged in. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could also modify directly the /etc/passwd file.

That way you don't need to logout the user nor stop any process being run by that user.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue but the user was not really logged in as `# w` did not return the user name. Rebooting the machine worked fine.